# Automatically Concatenating Tables from Multiple Pages - Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, web-scraping, automation

I am making a program that is trying to look at small companies and gather data on insider buying. The script below is able to gather data from every company in the larger table('http://openinsider.com/latest-penny-stock-buys') and fetch a table showing the data I want from each company.
It currently can print out each table separately, but I want to concatenate them all into one large table. The code is down below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np # for numeric python functions
from pylab import * # for easy matplotlib plotting
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url1='http://openinsider.com/latest-penny-stock-buys'
df1 = pd.read_html(url1)
table=df1[11]
#the table works - now lets make it look at change owned to find the largest value
#sorting
n = np.quantile(table['Qty'], [0.99])
print("99th percentile: ",n)
q=table.sort_values('Qty', ascending = False)
name=q['Ticker'].str.replace('\d+', '')
page = requests.get(url1)
name = (table['Ticker'])
n = name.count()
print(n)
#Buyers for the company
url = 'http://openinsider.com/'
for entry in name:
  table2 = pd.read_html(url+entry)
  dfn=table2[11]
```

I have a few ideas on how to tackle the problem, I'm just not sure how it can be formatted in python.
Thanks!

> So far tried counting the number of recursions, giving each table a respective value, and making a function that concats the previous table to the last one. However, I was not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I actually fooled around a bit and figured it out!

Basically just make a list, add each dfn every time the loop is done, and then you can apparently just concat the list:

```
List = []
url = 'http://openinsider.com/'
for entry in name:
  table2 = pd.read_html(url+entry)
  dfn=table2[11]
  List.append(dfn)
pd.concat(List)
```